# What simple open source photo/image editors exist there on android?

Tags: android, open-source, images, image-editor, photography

I want to edit photos and other images on my phone. Some features should be:

- Cropping
- Rotating
- Resizing/compression

Face-recognition for semi-autocrop is nice, but doesn't have to be. More features aren't needed, I'd obviously do more complicated editing on a computer.

Basically, I'm looking for an *open source* alternative to the non-open [Photo Editor](http://alternativeto.net/software/photo-editor-1/?license=free&platform=android-tablet).

Edit: Before you answer, please check whether the program you're talking about is actually Open Source, and state the license or link to the source code.

Comment: which mobile phone you are using ? btw Samsung devices provides these basic tasks in their own editing app(_note: am using Samsung device don't know about other manufacturers_)

Comment: @unique_id, a Samsung SIII. I wouldn't know any Samsung apps that allow you to do that, at least not on my device. And also, are they open source?

Comment: Open-Source might be the show-stopper here. Taking a look at my [list of photo editing apps](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/foto_edit), none of them seems to be available at F-Droid (which would be a true indicator for open-source). You still might wish to check the list to see what comes close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Phimp.me has the cropping/rotating features you mention, in addition to a wide range of other features. I haven't found a resize feature yet, though I haven't looked hard. There is apparently a feature to [resize/compress whole albums](https://blog.fossasia.org/compressing-albums-in-the-phimpme-android-application/).

The license is GNU-GPLv3 and the project is very active (35 commits in the last two weeks).

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.fossasia.phimpme&hl=en

https://github.com/fossasia/phimpme-android

[image: Phimp.me crop rotate screenshot]

Comment: It not really open source. Phimp.me [**needest Google Play Services dependency**](https://github.com/fossasia/phimpme-android/issues/1509) and [**use Facebook Analytics**](https://gitlab.com/fdroid/rfp/issues/655). Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try out these applications to crop, rotate and compress the size of the photo. These are open source lightweight image editing application on Android devices.

[REC Photo Editor by REC Labs](https://github.com/REC-LABS/REC_Photo_Editor)

[Android Image Edit](https://github.com/baugarten/Android-Image-Edit)

Comment: [REC photo editor](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rec.photoeditor) seems to actually work. The other one doesn't have a binary. Both aren't being developed anymore since 3 years.

Comment: What is the license of each? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Can't do photo resizing but the Gallery app from LineageOS, based on AOSP, does have cropping, rotation, and filters. I don't know if this source code is up to date, though, but it does look and work quite well.

http://lineageos.com/

https://github.com/LineageOS/android_packages_apps_Gallery2

Comment: What is its license?